# Write worksheet to csv when user closes Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have found all sorts of answers pertaining to closing a worksheet using a macro, but I need (ok want) to do something a bit different. When a user closes a workbook, I want to automatically write three worksheets out to a network drive. I can do the export no problem, but I'm drawing a blank launching the code when Excel gets closed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Explain a bit more please... macro writes three wks to drive and then closes excel... what are you trying to do after excel closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   'your code here...
End Sub
```

Comment: You are my new favorite person.